# how to use input() and match the elements with a database

Tags: python-3.x, input

```
database = {'User Name':['John frecks','Nadal alpha','Rick Ziani'],
         'Code':['9264','8345','2675']}



for i in database:
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    if name in database['User Name']:
        print('Welcome', name,'Enter your code')
    else:
        print('You are not a client! Enter your name again!')
        name = input('Enter your name: ')
        break
    code = input('Enter your code: ')
    if code in database['Code']:
        print('you are welcome')
        break
    else:
        print('your code is wrong!')
        break
```

The result I want,if all is right :

```
Enter your name: Nadal alpha
Enter your code: 8345
Your are welcome
```

The problem in my program is that whatever the code or the name are, I still get the same result.
For instance:

```
Enter your name: Nadal alpha
Enter your code: 2675 #this is Rick Ziani's code
You are welcome
```

Maybe, I didn't make the program the right way, if there is a way to optimize it, please tell me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your database isn't mapping between things in a useful way. Your keys are just constant strings, and the values are lists. Maybe you could use indexing into the lists to find out which code corresponds to which name, but there is a much better way.

Make your database dictionary map from name to code directly, with no lists:

```
database = {'John frecks': '9264', 'Nadal alpha': '8345', 'Rick Ziani': '2675'}
```

Now you can check if a name is know with `if name in database`. And you can lookup the corresponding code with `database[name]`.

Answer (score 1):

the way that you have designed your dictionary is not the best practice to create a dictionary. but for the sake of the question, lets take things as they are.

The problem is that you haven't made any relationships between codes and usernames except for their orders which means nothing to python in itself

here is how to fix it in your code, i'll include comments for convenience:

```
for i in database:
    user_index = 0 # you have to start a variable to be used in inner scopes
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    if name in database['User Name']:
        user_index = database['User Name'].index(name) # get the index of the entered name
        print('Welcome', name,'Enter your code')
        print(database['Code'][user_index])
    else:
        print('You are not a client! Enter your name again!')
        name = input('Enter your name: ')
        break
    code = input('Enter your code: ')
    if code in database['Code'] and code == database['Code'][user_index]:
        # in the second part of the line above, you make sure that code and name have the same index
        print('you are welcome')
        break
    else:
        print('your code is wrong!')
        break
```